# Changing the value of a variable in an SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, skaction

I've tried to change the value of an variable in an SKAction but it did not work and now I want to know if it is possible and if yes then how?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you please show some code of what you tried but did not work?

Comment: I don't have any specific code, I just want to know if there is a way to change the value of a variable. e.g. from false to true

Comment: No idea what you want to do. There are multiple values in an `SKAction`. Clear that up please.

Comment: Ok I will express myself more clearly.

When I declare a global variable in my class and this variable has the value of 10, can I change the value of the variable from 10 to 20 using an SKAction?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I mean yes, you can but it's not animatable anyways.

Comment: Yes I know that it is not animatable but I'd like to know how it works because it would solve a problem I have.

Comment: Then show your problem and people may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, you will set up an `SKAction` to run a block like so:

```
let anAction = SKAction.runBlock {
    myVariable += 10
}
someNode.runAction(anAction)
```